# Is this "listMerging" code improvable?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a method who merge two lists. The two merged lists are lists of subtypes objects of the returned list. By "merging" I mean "Allowing duplicates".

So Sub1 and Sub2 types are subtypes from Sup1 type.

Here is my code

```
var listSub1 = new List<Sub1>(); //With some content added..
var listSub2 = new List<Sub2>(); //With content too..  
var listToReturn = new List<Sup1>();
listToReturn.AddRange(listSub1.Select(item => item as Sup1).ToList());
listToReturn.AddRange(listSub2.Select(item => item as Sup1).ToList());

return listeToReturn;
```

It is working fine but I wonder if it is the best way to merge and cast the lists.

Comment: LINQ has a `Cast<T>` method which does the same thing, but is more readable and imho elegant (`listSub1.Cast<Sup1>()`). `return listSub1.Cast<Sup1>().Concat(listSub2.Cast<Sup1>()).ToList();` would be what I'd use.

Comment: @Morawski syntax error. apologies. I corrected it

Comment: ok so I edited this part out of my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could write

```
var newList = 
  listSub1.Cast<Sup1>()
  .Concat(listSub2.Cast<Sup1>()).ToList();
```

Note that `Union` is not correct to be used, since it will make sure that objects that are "equal" will come out only once.

Comment: It depends what he means by 'merge'

Comment: So Union() don't allows "duplicates" i the list? But Concat yes?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri `Union` is indeed O(n). It iterates through each item in both sequences (an O(n) operation), inserts the results into a hash-based set (O(1)) and skips if it had already been returned. Doing an O(1) thing n times is O(n). It has higher constant costs that `Concat`, but in a case where either was acceptable the skipping could make it faster depending on the number of duplicates.

Comment: @Jon Hanna, I don't think union is works in the way you said, but if it works in this way, the average running time is O(n) not exact time, this can be O(n log n) in collision free hash, If you say there is such a hash with O(1) exact running time (in find and insert), Also there is possible collisions, So Union is not good.

Comment: There's possible collisions, but barring a really poor `GetHashCode()` or deliberately hitting the worse case as part of a Denial of Service attack, it'll be close to O(1), making Union close to O(n). I don't see where you are getting O(n log n) from, can you explain? Generally, either `Union` is the only sensible thing or `Concat` is the only sensible things, but if either could work the fact that `Union` skips some elements would mean the nett effect was faster with sufficient duplicates skipped.

Answer (score 3):

```
return listSub1.Cast<Sup1>().Concat(list2.Cast<Sup1>()).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = listSub1.AddRang(listSub2 ).Cast<Sup1>().ToList()
```

Comment: has a side effect that OPs code does not. it changes listSub1. What if he needs the original afterwards?

Comment: @RuneFS , You are right in general, but if you see the OPs signature, seems both sub list will be created in one fuction, and there is no need to them after return of function.

Comment: If they were indeed created then why create two? if they are on the other hand returned from a different method (not new'ed) then you're reasoning no longer holds.

Comment: @Rune FS, these all depends to OPs situation and this was my observation from sample code, but I suggested to use AddRange (native list method) to have a faster run time, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [LINQ's Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993.aspx)? That should to the trick.

Comment: because it does not produce the same result. Duplicates are removed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I don't have to keep binary compatibility with an older released version, I'd redefine the return type as `IEnumerable<Sub1>` and code it as:

```
return listSub1.Concat(listSub2);
```

If a caller really needs a list, it can call `.ToList()` itself, but a caller that doesn't need a list (e.g. it's just going to `foreach` through it all) needn't suffer the delay and memory use of `.ToList()`.

Using `.ToList()` only when needed is a micro-opt as a single change, but as a coding habit can begin to add up significantly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with linq:

```
var listToReturn = listSub1.Cast<Sup1>().Concat(listSub2).ToList();
```

edit: to match the edited question

Comment: that behaves differently. The .Cast<> will throw if it can't cast OP simply "inserts" a null.

Comment: Yes but the question says: So Sub1 and Sub2 types are subtypes from Sup1 type so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: and union does not produce the concatenation of the two lists but the set union. That is duplicates are removed

Comment: 'the best way to merge and cast the lists..', so it depends on your interpretation of the merge word

Comment: I qoute "is working fine". OPs code does not remove duplicates and is working fine